# Google forms - Handling events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been stuck on the same problem since the weekend (last 3 days) and I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

I have a simple form with a drop down.

Upon selecting a value from the drop down I would like to either:

- Open another form which has been created using apps script with bespoke form items
- Or populate the same form with bespoke form items.

I have an onSubmit trigger in the form which points to the following function:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var name;
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; ++i) {
    if (itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle() == "Select your name") {
      name = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log("The name given is %s", name);

 // Create and open a form.
 var newForm = FormApp.create(name + "'s form");
 var list = newForm.addListItem();
 list.createChoice("one");
 list.createChoice("two");
 list.createChoice("three");
}
```

I know this function gets called as I get info in the logs, but no new form appears.

Can you please enlighten me and let me know what I might be doing wrong?

Failing this I wouldn't mind if I was able to create items in the same form, but I also tried this to no avail

Regards
Crouz

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can open another form directly from the current form.  You would need some intermediary step.  You can create a new form with code, and get the URL to that form.  But then you need to get the URL to the user somehow.  You can email them the new URL in the form of a hyperlink in an email.  There is no way to open the new form in a browser without that link.

You would need a Stand Alone Web App written in HTML to be able to have more flexibility and more options.